# Service v/s AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-service

I am confused with respect to design of my app. I need to continuously poll a server to get new data from it. I am confused whether Async Task running at fixed interval or Service running is background is better option. The thread will run only when the app is running

Answer (score 5):

You have already some answers to your question, but I think it worths a summary ...

**What you need**

When you want to run a peice of code that takes some time to complete you should always run it in a separate thread from the UI thread.

You can achieve that in 2 ways:

Using `Thread`:

This is the simplest one, if you don't need a lot of communication from the new thread to the UI thread. If you need the communication, you will probably have to use a `Handler` to do it.

Using `AsyncTask`:

Also runs in a separate thread and already implements some communications channels with the UI thread. So this one is preferable if you need this communication back to the UI.

**What you don't need**

`Service`

This serves mainly to keep some code running even after you exit the main application, and it will run in the UI thread unless you spawn a new thread using the options described above. You said that your thread are suposed to terminate when you exit application, so this is not what you need.

`IntentService`

This can be activated by an external event (i.e. `BroadcastReceiver`) that can start a piece of code defined by you, even if your application is not running. Once again, based on your requirements, this is not what you are looking for.

Regards.

Comment: In stead of a Thread, you can use an Executor. And you do need a service, if you want polling to continue when Android removes your app from the stack. You don't want it to continue, then Service is overhead that you don't need.

Comment: I disagree with point 3 abouts services. You state "You said that your thread are suposed to terminate when you exit application, so this is not what you need.", this is correct. But what about configuration changes? Screen orientation changing and the user intercepting a call? - Otherwise well written!

Answer (score 2):

an [Android Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) is not in a background thread.

Therefore you should have a Service running that will start an ASyncTask each time you want to poll.

> Note that services, like other application objects, run in the main thread of their hosting process. This means that, if your service is going to do any CPU intensive (such as MP3 playback) or blocking (such as networking) operations, it should spawn its own thread in which to do that work. More information on this can be found in Processes and Threads. The IntentService class is available as a standard implementation of Service that has its own thread where it schedules its work to be done.

Answer (score 1):

`Service` should not be compared to `AsyncTask`. I guess you most likely meant `IntentService` here - and this is slightly different thing than `Service`, despite the common name.

As for periodical fetching, I'd stick with recurrent alarm (using `AlarmManager`) and (most likely) use `IntentService` to do the fetching.

Here you got with [AsyncTask fundamentals](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and some [tutorials](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html)
And here you got with [IntentService fundamentals](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) and [tutorials](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html)

Note, that `IntentService` jobs are queued by design, while `AsyncTasks` can run fully paralel. However be aware of [regression related to AsyncTask handling in newer APIs](http://commonsware.com/). Not a big deal as workaround is just a few more code lines, however it's worth knowing that.

**EDIT**

There's misunderstanding floating among many concerning AsyncTask lifecycle being bond to Activity's life cycle. This is **WRONG**. AsyncTask is independent from an Activity. Finishing Activity does not do anything to any AsyncTasks, unless you are cleaning them up from onDestroy() by your code. Yet, if an activity's process is being killed while it is in the background, then AsyncTask will also be killed as well, as part of the entire process being killed

Comment: Isn't IntentService more of a queue type architecture ?

Comment: Yes it is, but I assume it is not a problem for periodical fetching, unless fetching can overlap. I personally mostly use `AsyncTask` but it all depends on app architecture.

Comment: Also I have one more doubt. Like Async Task is linked with a UI thread. But this polling will start independent of UI and no notification need to be given to user so I guess that might rule out one of the optios

Answer (score 1):

If you want to "continuously poll", an asyncTask won't do. The task stops when your app gets stopped by Android. A Service by itself won't do either, as Blundell already pointed out. A Service runs in the main thread, and you don't want to do polling in the main thread. There's two ways of doing it: you create a Service that spawns its own thread to do the stuff you want it to do, or you let it schedule polls that are executed in an AsyncTask or in a separate thread. I try not to have polling in my app, but if you have to, creating a special thread in your service that does the polling seems best to me.

Depending on what your app does and what the polling is about, you can give the separate thread a lower priority, so it doesn't get in the way of other processing.

Comment: **That's sort of urban legend** AsyncTask is **independent from an Activity**. Finishing Activity does not do anything to any AsyncTasks, unless you are cleaning them up from onDestroy() by your code. Yet, if an activity's **process** is being killed while it is in the background, then AsyncTask will also be killed as well, as part of the entire process being killed.

Comment: So what's your point? AsyncTask will not make sure that the app keeps polling, because when Android needs the space, it destroys the app and polling stops. In a Service, polling continues. The fact that I say "activity stops" rather than "app gets stopped", that a reason for you to vote my answer down? Pathetic....

Comment: You were spreading false information. That was my point at first. Second, AsyncTask is not for periodical tasks, as stated in my answer. An finally, if you cannot take criticism, maybe you should not join the conversation in the first place.

Comment: Whatever. As long as you're happy.

Comment: @WebnetMobile.com: in what way was Christine "spreading" wrong information? App is not equal to Activity, you're the one who misrepresents her post (and then later you added her thoughts as an edit to the end of your post -- maybe you're the one who needs to learn to accept criticism?). She is right that if the app gets killed, the AsyncTasks will stop too (just like every other thread, considering that the whole process is killed). Even if the OP has said that polling is only needed as long as the app is running, this still doesn't mean Christine spread any wrong info.

Comment: WebMobile, I didn't say that asynctask is for periodical tasks. I said a service is suited better for that, and of course you'll need a handler or something of the kind. The asynctask or the thread you need to run the thing off the ui thread. And I know that my wording is not always as precise as some people apparently want it to be, I know that, but you did get the point, I hope.

Answer (score 0):

> The thread will run only when the app is running

Then `AsyncTask` will be the simplest solution. Send data periodically to app thread using `publishProgress()` from background thread. Set desired interval using `Thread.sleep()` in `doInBackground()`. Also, make sure you start a *new* task in `onResume()` method of Activity, and end this task in `onPause()` method of Activity.

Example:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private AsyncTask<Void,String,Void> mAsyncTask;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mAsyncTask = new MyTask();
        mAsyncTask.execute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if(mAsyncTask != null){
            mAsyncTask.cancel(true);
        }
    }

    private void onServerResponse(String response){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Got response !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private final class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void,String,Void>{

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            while (!isCancelled()){

                String response = "";

                //server query code here

                publishProgress(response);
                Log.i("TEST", "Response received");

                //sleep for 5 sec, exit if interrupted ,likely due to cancel(true) called
                try{
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                }catch (InterruptedException e){
                    return null;
                }
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
            if(values.length > 0){
                onServerResponse(values[0]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```