# Service or Asynctask for sampling sensors in Android?

Tags: android, android-service, android-sensors

I've to acquire data from various sensors like accelerometer, gyroscope, microphone and GPS.
The sensing action shouldn't be continuous, but rather single short intervals of sampling should be periodically scheduled according to various policy (for example power saving). Each sensor sampling action lasts few seconds, say 5 seconds.
I would realize a "Client" for each sensor, deputed to the listening of sensor data when necessary, and a "Controller" that control the execution of Clients, but I'm not sure about the way to realize this.

Is it correct to realize a Service for each Client? or would be better a simple AsyncTask or Handler?

It's better if each Client is responsible of a single sensing action, executed in a single onStartService(), or if the onStartService() action enable a periodic action of sampling?
Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a task for a `Service`, that is triggered by `Alarm`s at (regular) scheduled intervals.

An `AsyncTask` is usually something that is started after the user has done some interaction and the system is supposed to do a "long running" operation (like network i/o), which could otherwise block the UI.

Note that it is very well possible to also trigger a service like an `AsyncTask` - have a look at `IntentService`.

Comment: so the Controller controls the scheduling of each single sensing action executed by each Service properly setting the repeating period of each Client? It's sounds good! Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, of course each Client spawns it's own thread to compute a sensing action, so i will use Intent Service for some CLients, or Looper/Handler for others (if sensor events are dispatched in a Listener). Also, all this components (Controllers and Clients) are totally detached from UI elements since they run in a separate process, and they don't even communicate with the UI.

Comment: After a further reading, seems that Alarm is conceived for a more sporadic periodicity. In my case, the events are scheduled with period from 30 seconds to 30 minutes. Is it ok to use Alarm so repeatedly? For now i'm using Timer from Java..

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you have a look at my answer regarding a similar question here: [Service v/s AsyncTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13110047/service-v-s-asynctask/13110770#13110770).

Personally, I would use a simple `Handler` to post a task to run with a specific time interval.

Example:

```
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

private void startTimer(Runnable Task, long delay) {  
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(Task);       
    mHandler.postDelayed(Task, delay);    
}

private void stopTimer(Runnable Task) {  
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(Task);       
}

private Runnable registerListeners = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        startTimer(registerListeners, 10*60*1000); //register to run again in 10 minutes
        startTimer(unregisterListeners, 5*1000); //to unregister in 5 seconds 
        //here register your listeners
    }
};

private Runnable unregisterListeners = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        //here unregister your listeners
    }
};
```

When you want to start the listening process:

```
//To start you listeners
startTimer(registerListeners, 0);
```

When you want to stop everyting:

```
//To stop registering/unregistering listeners
stopTimer(registerListeners);
```

**Note:** If you are doing long running code in your listeners, then you should have a look to the answer in the link I gave above.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Best practices from android developers site

[Best Practices for Accessing and Using Sensors](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview.html#sensors-practices)

[Best Practices for Background Jobs](http://developer.android.com/training/best-background.html)

Comment: While these links may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.